# Php get values without submitting

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

I have a html form with 5 fields.

1. Code
2. Qty
3. Details
4. Rate
5. Subtotal

I want to get values for Details, Rate from sql DB without submitting or refreshing the form/page.

And also get subtotal values as I enters code and qty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use Ajax

Comment: I have no idea how to use it. Im just a beginner. If you know, can you help. Once i see the codes, i will understand it and modify accordingly. Thankx

Comment: I have not, cox i don't know ajax and javascript much

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please do read some reference and try something before posting here. "once I see the code I will understand it"... Woooo no need to learn during days, you are a genius

Comment: @AhmedHusham  first try to read,understand  about ajax,javascript and jQuery. Do some code yourself and then come back if you are facing any problem. Always remember to show your code-effort. It encourages people to give answer happely.

Comment: Thanx. Accepted. I will try again, and post again if failed again. 

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Ajax`. You use `JavaScript` to get the data in the background without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can send files and  data in background in ajax  and you can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)
class  to send what you want as object
for simplicity you can use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) this is the javascript code

```js
 $("#form").submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        data1:$("input[name=data1]").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.php",
        data: data,
        type:"post",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="data1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

and in file.php  you will chek for $_POST('data1')